# What do arranging and assigning mean in sequence annotation?

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics

Please could someone explain these lines to me in a simple way

> These sequences were then arranged based on some overlapping regions present in them. This required generation of overlapping fragments for sequencing. These sequences were subsequently annotated and assigned to each chromosome

What do "arranging" and "assigning" mean in this context?

Source: [NCERT class 12](http://ncertbooks.prashanthellina.com/class_12.Biology.Biology/06Molecular%20Basis%20of%20Inhertance.pdf) (This text in in reference to the method developed by Frederick Sanger)

Comment: I edited the post to improve its format. Feel free to roll back if you don't like it. Would be great if you could link to the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word "arranged" means simply alignment of sequence based on overlapping regions in two sequences. For example:

```
Seq1: AGTGTCCGTCGTAAGTCA

Seq2:GTCGTAAGTCATCGAGATACC
```

leading to:

```
Seq12: AGTGTCCGTCGTAAGTCATCGAGATACC
```

Maybe he used the word "arrange" as overlapping determines the direction of resultant sequence (for which word alignment is sufficient)

Assignment: Is simply dividing the genome's sequence down as per chromosomes of the species. Like for example, if it's human genome sequence and first chromosome is 2,50,000bp long (just assumption - I don't remember exact figure), then first 2,50,000 nucleotides in the sequence will be "assigned" to chromosome 1. From 2,50,001 onwards to chromosome 2 and so on..

Comment: @Felix_17 Pleasure! :)